# Rails 3 - Basic Application Bootstrapping - What scripts/projects/templates do you use and are the most configurable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, web-applications, bootstrapping

https://github.com/search?q=bootstrap&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1

I'm currently working on a very basic web application bootstrap that would allow users to get up and running with the following defaults:

basic auth (Devise)
HAML
jQuery
Faker (gem for autopopulation of db)
Typus (gem for admin)

Do you know of any good templates/script/projects that do something similar?

I can remember a site a while back that basically had a selection page that created a template for you for Rails 2.3. Is there something similar to that for Rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

All template use on Rails 2.3.x works with Rails 3, if all plugin are maintain.

Comment: Yes, but do you know of any generators?

Comment: With that I mean, do you know of something that could take say the Categorization of the Ruby Toolbox, and have you choose one of the top 3 authentication gems? Compound your choices into a template? I'm basically talking about application recipes here.